# ASP.net Core SignalR: Server returned Handshake error: handshake was cancelled after successful connection

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I am trying to connect my client application with the `IHubContext` defined on the server. When I am trying this in my local system with localhost, everything works perfectly fine as below screen shot and I can receive `SignalR` messages.

[image]

But when I deploy my application on `IIS server` and then try to connect to that using my client, I get `Handshake cancelled message`, after successful connection. What is the problem?

[image]

Please note that I have checked `WebSockets` are enabled on my server using `Server Manager` and `IIS`. Below is my client code (which works perfectly fine on `localhost`.

```
"use strict";
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:53832/api/NotificationHub?userName=rtg0000003@maq.qa", {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    configureLogging: "warn",
    withHandshakeResponseTimeout: 3000000,
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets 
    //,headers :  {jwtBearer: tokenValue}
}).configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
    .build();
connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000000;
connection.on("NotifyClient", (response) => {
    var heading = document.createElement("h3");
    heading.textContent = response.useR_NAME;
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerText = response.subject;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(heading);
    div.appendChild(p); document.getElementById("articleList").appendChild(div);
});
connection.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
}).then(function () {
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "UserId: " + userId;
    connection.invoke("GetConnectionId").then(function (connectionId) {
        document.getElementById("signalRConnectionId").innerHTML = connectionId;
    })
});
```

I have set `app.UseWebSockets()` in `Configure` method of `Startup` file as well.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should add  this attributes on startup file in .NET Core :

1. EnableDetailedErrors
2. KeepAliveInterval
3. HandshakeTimeout

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
  services.AddSignalR(hubOptions => {    
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;    
    hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); 
    hubOptions.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Open cmd with administrator, then input below command.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://:<ip_address>:53832/ user="NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
```

Comment: can you provide some description of above? and also, I assume this has to be done on the server hosting the application right? I will request the release team to run this and see if it works

Comment: @WAQ I found the tips [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692295/netsh-http-add-urlacl-problem), you can try it.